# How do I get the 64x64 icon of a file type/extension in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, icons

Ok so the title is, once again, straight forward.
I need to extract the 16x16 icon of a file extension, and it works.
But the other (large) size is 32x32 or 48x48 (Can't remember at the moment).
But for my interface I need the 64x64 icon of the file type.

How do I extract it?
P.S. The faster, the better, 'cuz I am gonna need to extract lots of icons.

Comment: My personal favourite is [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775703(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this logic from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/filetoiconconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a MultiIcon object to iterate through the icons.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/MultiIcon.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [another site](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234043-how-extract-specific-icon-ico-file):

```
Icon icon1 = IconFactory(@"C:\hoge.ico", 64, 64);
```

Also, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648075.aspx

Comment: Ah, it is so hard to read source code without syntax highlighting... And I also don't have paths to .ico files... Just a file extension.

Comment: of course you could use the C# file methods to loop through a certain folder and read all .ico or .exe files, instead of using hard coded paths